# How to convert below javascript procedure to SQL procedure snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to convert a JavaScript procedure to a SQL stored procedure.

This code is working fine, but I need to convert it into a SQL stored procedure. I'm trying to get it converted but I get some errors...

```
call extract_keys_from_json();
        RETURNS STRING
        LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
        EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    $$
      var sql_command = '';
      var key_list = [];
    
   Assume `edata` is the column name of your JSON blob
      var query = `SELECT OBJECT_KEYS(edata) AS keys FROM Json_data LIMIT 1`;
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query});
      var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    
      if (resultSet.next()) {
        key_list = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
      }
    
    Construct the SELECT statement to extract each key


  sql_command = 'SELECT ';
      for (var i = 0; i < key_list.length; i++) {
        sql_command += 'edata:"' + key_list[i] + '" AS "' + key_list[i] + '"';
        if (i < key_list.length - 1) {
          sql_command += ', ';
        }
      }
      sql_command += ' FROM json_data';
    
      // Return the constructed SQL command
      return sql_command;
    $$;
```

Comment: Hi - please update your question to include the SQL Proc you've managed to write and the errors you are getting

Comment: the signature of your procedure is not correct.  `call extract_keys_from_json();
        RETURNS STRING`  should be producing an error.    I will echo what @NickW stated, post the SQL proc and errors.   What you have shown so far is invalid.